# What is the best way to deploy NopCommerce 3.0 to Windows Azure using a Web Role?

Tags: azure, deployment, nopcommerce, webrole

I need to deploy a NopCommerce application on Windows Azure using Web Role. I created the Cloud project and added Nop.Web to Web Role, but it doesnt work! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blogpost I've written here - [Hosting nopCommerce on Windows Azure Web Sites with Automatic Source Control Deployment](http://www.pronopcommerce.com/hosting-nopcommerce-on-windows-azure-web-sites-with-automatic-source-control-deployment?utm_source=stackoverflow_com) - might give you some inspiration. :)